# Locked, Deleted Question that should be Undeleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Many times a year, I see a question like [Will First Name + Last Name + Date Of Birth combination be unique enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569679/will-first-name-last-name-date-of-birth-combination-be-unique-enough). When that happens, I search my favorites for a question I *know* I answered with a good example of a long name - with the intention of saying "no" to this new question. I could never find it. Now I know why. It's been deleted.

"[What is the longest human name you can expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128099/what-is-the-longest-human-name-you-can-expect)" (linked for 10k users) was closed and locked in 2011, but was then deleted in 2012. I think that closing and locking were sufficient.

Some of the answers would be very helpful to someone trying to decide how to handle human names in a program.

Comment: Here is an other question *(for 10K users)*: [Visual Studio optimizations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations)

Comment: What is so incredibly useful about that question? A bunch of random examples of long names? I only see one answer in there that even attempted to analyze the problem in a constructive way, and it's half-way down the page.

Comment: Even the random examples of long names are useful to someone trying to convince Management that varchar(30) isn't enough to store a first or last name. I have had many discussions with analysts, managers, etc. who just don't believe that names can get long. I suspect this is because many people coming to the US "americanize" their names rather than having their names butchered.

Comment: There's also the "but of _course_ they have a last name" factor.

Comment: Note also that I'm not talking about unlocking it - just undeleting it. It should remain locked.